# React Native SectionList scroll to the top while refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-sectionlist

I am using a [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist) to display a list of data. I have a top menu where a users can click these buttons to display a different set of data on the list, think of it like tabs. All this is working fine, the correct data is being shown and it's refreshing properly.

However the problem is that when a user scrolls down, say halfway, on the list then clicks one of the buttons at the top the list does not show the `refreshing` animation (the spinning circle) anymore. I have correctly implemented the `refreshing` property and that works whenever I pull down to refresh.

Also if you scroll to the top of the list then click one of the buttons the refresh icon also shows up as intended. The problem is whenever you scroll down the list and then set the `refreshing` property the list does not show the icon.

```
<SectionList
refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
onRefresh={() => this.onRefreshList()}
....
...
/>
```

Then whenever I make a call to start updating the data...

```
this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() {
....
....
//all code in here works fine the list shows activity monitor no problems
//when you scroll down on the list THEN 
//call this the activity monitor can't be seen on the list
});
```

So to counteract this I tried to [scroll to the top](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#scrolltolocation) automatically before calling my actual refresh. This *kinda of* works but it looks really bad. There is no callback so I don't know when the list has completed scrolling to the top.

```
//this also works properly and scrolls the list to the top but
//it's really jumpy and looks terrible because the data is immediately 
//replaced while it's scrolling to the top, the loading animation can't be seen.

 this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({
      animated: true,
      sectionIndex: 0,
      itemIndex: 0,
      viewPosition: 0
    });
```

---

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds or am I just doing something wrong here?